# Multiple .use() on the same router are causing overwritten callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, consign

I'm using a module called [consign](https://www.npmjs.com/package/consign) to include several different modules in a directory at once (instead of having a bunch of require statements). Within these modules, I've been setting the mount path for each endpoint at the top of the router file so as not to repeat it several times throughout the file. However, consign passes the same router to each of these (which should normally be fine) and the mount path is actually being overwritten via the use() method if the path is the same in any of the files. I'll try and show this the best way I can...

**/routes/api.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var consign = require('consign');

// get all routes inside the api directory and attach them to the api router
// all of these routes should be behind authorization
consign({
  cwd: 'routes'
})
  .include('api')
  .into(router);

module.exports = router;
```

**/routes/api/player.js**

```
module.exports = function (router) {
  router.use('/player', router);

  router.get('/getInfo', function (req, res, next) {
    res.error = false;
    res.data = {};
    res.message = "Player getInfo API Call - IN DEVELOPMENT";
    next();
  });
};
```

**/routes/api/profile.js**

```
module.exports = function (router) {
  router.use('/profile', router);

  router.get('/getInfo', function (req, res, next) {
    res.error = false;
    res.data = {};
    res.message = "Profile getInfo API Call - IN DEVELOPMENT";
    next();
  });
}
```

Consign is loading in the modules just fine, but the router.use() method seems to be overwriting the callbacks when the paths are the same (disregarding the base path that is). For instance, both "/player/getInfo" and "/profile/getInfo" work as a call, but are both responding with "/profile/getInfo" data.

BTW - in case you're wondering and in case it's pertinent, I have a small piece of middleware called "formatResponse" that will take the data and format all of the calls in the same way, which is why I have a "next()" instead responding from the function itself. The code for that is below as well.

**/middleware/formateResponse.js**

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  res.json({
    error: res.error,
    data: res.data,
    message: res.message
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're doing it right now, there's no scope. The fact that you mounted the router on '/profile' and then added a get statement to the '/getInfo' path doesn't really change the scope the way you think it does.  They're both stored to match on '/getInfo', with the last one in winning (regardless of prefix. I bet navigating to http://your-server/getInfo will work too).

You either need to use a different router for each module (and then mount that one on the path root you want) or else be more explicit in the rest of the routes (e.g. call `router.get('/profile/getInfo', ...)`.